# Return array of hashes based on hash element match

Tags: ruby, hash

I am wondering how one would search through an array of hashes and return a value based on a search string. For example, `@contacts` contains the hash elements: `:full_name`, `:city`, and `:email`. The variable `@contacts` (I guess it would be an array) contains three entries (perhaps rows). Below is the code I have so far to conduct a search based on `:city` value. However it's not working. Can anyone give me an idea what's going on?

```
def search string
  @contacts.map {|hash| hash[:city] == string}
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `select` instead of `map`:

```
def search string
  @contacts.select { |hash| hash[:city] == string }
end
```

In your code you tried to `map` (or transform) your array using a block, which yields boolean values. `map` takes a block and invokes the block for each element of `self`, constructing a new array containing elements returned by the block. As the result, you got an array of booleans.

`select` works similar. It takes a block and iterates over the array as well, but instead of transforming the source array it returns an array containing elements for which the block returns `true`. So it's a selection (or filtering) method.

In order to understand the difference between these two methods it's useful to see their example definitions:

```
class Array
  def my_map
    [].tap do |result|
      self.each do |item|
        result << (yield item)
      end
    end
  end

  def my_select
    [].tap do |result|
      self.each do |item|
        result << item if yield item
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
irb(main):007:0> [1,2,3].my_map { |x| x + 1 }
[2, 3, 4]
irb(main):008:0> [1,2,3].my_select { |x| x % 2 == 1 }
[1, 3]
irb(main):009:0>
```

Comment: This worked. In your answer though, does this syntax basically tell the program to separate each element for inspection: { |hash| hash[:city] == string }

Comment: @NealR, yes this is a syntax for a block, i.e. a piece of code which is invoked for each item of the array (in case of passing the block to `select`). The resulting array will contain only those items, for which the block holds `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 def search string
    @contacts.select{|hash| h[:city].eql?(string) }
 end
```

This will return an array of hashes which matches string.